# Why i cant see this image button on IE8 with this CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So, this is the html code for the button

```
<input type="submit" name="logueo" value="log" id="sendbu"/>
```

And this is the css style

```
#sendbu     { width: 50px; height: 34px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background: transparent url(lock.png) no-repeat center top; border: 0;   text-indent: -1000em; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }
```

All this works on Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the button seams to dont exist. Thanks for the help.

Comment: this is not a solution to your problem , but it does seem to be a error in your code .. "cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@domingo why text-indent - 1000em , ie does a different calculation on negative margins , try to remove that and check once

Comment: Now works on IE but i see a text over the image, what can i do?

Comment: @domingo give appropriate position for the text , for some reason it is overlaping right, can you post your code in fiddle , we can easily fix it.

Comment: Good call on the CSS. @DomingoSL Validate the CSS to ensure it's cross-browser compliant. Best

Answer (score 1):

`font-size: 0;` works sometimes.  I'm sure there are sites that use negative indent that work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `background: transparent url(lock.png) center top no-repeat;`, and also the '`name`' and '`id`' properties should match, different flavours of Browser use 'name' differently.

Comment: I agree, the "id" and "name" attributes should match. Especially for IE. Best

Comment: @OVWeb Solutions Why should they match? Because of IE's old `document.getElementById()` getting the name attribute too?

Comment: @domingo why text-indent - 1000em , ie does a different calculation on negative margins , try to remove that and check once

Comment: @gov Now works on IE but i see a text over the image, what can i do?

Comment: @alex I believe they share the same name space in IE.  You can test this with Javascript as well. Say for instance, you have <div id="MessageBoard"></div>, and in Javascript, you create an object with the same name:  var MessageBoard = new MsgBoard();... IE will fail to instantiate the object due to the naming conventions. You would have to rename one or the other.

Comment: @OVWeb Solutions IE's `document.getElementById('bob')` will select `<input name="bob" />`, that is what I was trying to get at :)